# How to solve CredSSP Encryption error when trying RDP

Tags: credssp

I get this error when I connect with RDP
This could be due to CredSSP encryption oracle remediation.

For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866660

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Microsoft made this bad change but I will solve it for you :-)
Run cmd as Administrator (Search for cmd and right click with the mouse to choose RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR).

You can also use powershell admin.
Copy and paste this command to run it and rate my answer if succeed :-)

REG  ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters\ /v AllowEncryptionOracle /t REG_DWORD /d 2

Comment: I am glad to help!

Comment: @Asi please make a note that the registry change will now make your machine vulnerable when connecting to unpatched servers. The _real_ fix is to patch the server you're trying to connect to via RDP.

Comment: Worked for me as well..
Thnx

Comment: This is the best solution which requires less actions.

Answer (score -2):

create a text file: **rd_patch.reg**

Paste following content, save and double-click it.

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters]
>   "AllowEncryptionOracle"=dword:00000002

Solution from: https://serverfault.com/a/911645